# CSS Animation acting weird

Tags: html, css

## ***Found Fix, DO NOT REPLY***

So I'm making my images zoom in one at a time. My logo works fine but when I try to do some of my icons they are stretched out and in the first animation all of them start to load. It shows in the JSFiddle.

HTML:

```
<div class="main">
    <div id="logo"><img src="img/logo.png" /></div>
    <div id="main-links">
        <a style="cursor:pointer"><img id="img-1" style="margin-left: 0" src="img/icons/forums.png" onmouseover="this.src='img/icons/forums-hover.png'" onmouseout="this.src='img/icons/forums.png'" /></a>
        <a style="cursor:pointer"><img id="img-2" src="img/icons/servers.png" onmouseover="this.src='img/icons/servers-hover.png'" onmouseout="this.src='img/icons/servers.png'" /></a>
        <a style="cursor:pointer"><img id="img-3" src="img/icons/staff.png" onmouseover="this.src='img/icons/staff-hover.png'" onmouseout="this.src='img/icons/staff.png'" /></a>
        <a style="cursor:pointer"><img id="img-4" src="img/icons/donate.png" onmouseover="this.src='img/icons/donate-hover.png'" onmouseout="this.src='img/icons/donate.png'" /></a>
    </div>
</div>
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/z0yc6rsw/) (Images were changed just for the exaple)

Comment: Can you phrase your problem in the form of a question?

Comment: Nothing is strange, the original image is 800px in size and you are placing it in a smaller container, so they are stretched out to fit-in as the page loads. Just use smaller images, good luck.

Comment: Ok, but what about all of them coming in at once on the first icon animation, then disappearing are zooming in one at a time for the rest of the icons, like they are suppose to.

Comment: @RuslanAbuzant would you know anything about that?

Comment: Never mind, I just decided to use javascript instead off css

Answer (score 0):

You have a few issues.

1) By default, CSS animation beginning/end states on DOM elements do not persist. That means that you'll have your object exactly as it's coded up until the animation runs, then the animation takes effect, and then it returns to its original state.

To overcome this, you need to use the css property `animation-fill-mode` on your images. You can set this to `none` (default), `backwards` (the beginning frame of the animation is the appearance until the animation runs), `forwards` (the final frame of the animation is the appearance after the animation runs), or `both` (the appearance is dictated by the '0%' animation state until the animation runs, the animation runs, and then its appearance is dictated by the '100%' animation state).

2) Your animation sets the `100%` state for the images at `height:100%; width:100%;`. That means that when the animation runs, it sets the size of the images to the container element's width (`width:100%`) by the container element's height (`height:100%`, which is ignored in this case because the container doesn't have an explicit height). That's why the images get so stretched out as they animate in.

To overcome this, you need to set the `100%` state's width and height properties to `inherit` (`height:inherit; width:inherit;`) so that they take the width and height from the other rules or the image's natural size instead of trying to stretch to match the container.

See updated code:

```css
@keyframes zoomin {
    0% { height: 0; width: 0; /*margin: 45% 45%;*/ }
    100% { height: inherit; width: inherit; /*margin: 0% 0%;*/ }
}

#logo {
    margin-top: -350px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
}

#logo img {
    width: 398px;
    height: 391px;
    animation: pulse 1s linear infinite;
    animation: zoomin 0.7s ease-in;
}

.main {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    margin-top: 100px;
    transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
    width: 100%;
}

#main-links {
    position: absolute;
    width: 873px;
    height: 205px;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translateX(-50%);
    margin-top: -90px;
}

#main-links img {
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    margin-left: 20px;
    animation-fill-mode: backwards;
}

#img-1 {
    animation: zoomin 0.7s ease-in;
    animation-delay: 0.7s;
}

#img-2 {
    animation: zoomin 0.7s ease-in;
    animation-delay: 1.4s;
}

#img-3 {
    animation: zoomin 0.7s ease-in;
    animation-delay: 2.1s;
}

#img-4 {
    animation: zoomin 0.7s ease-in;
    animation-delay: 2.8s;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
        <div id="logo"><img src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/reactjs/redux/master/logo/logo.png" /></div>
        <div id="main-links">
            <a><img id="img-1" style="margin-left: 0" src="https://openclipart.org/image/800px/svg_to_png/130729/Awesome-template.png" /></a>
            <a><img id="img-2" src="https://openclipart.org/image/800px/svg_to_png/130729/Awesome-template.png"/></a>
            <a><img id="img-3" src="https://openclipart.org/image/800px/svg_to_png/130729/Awesome-template.png"/></a>
            <a><img id="img-4" src="https://openclipart.org/image/800px/svg_to_png/130729/Awesome-template.png" /></a>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Also, if you're wondering why the first image grows down and right while the other three grow up and right, it's because the images are growing from the text baseline. The first one appears to grow down, because the text baseline is actually lowering to accommodate the height of the image. After the text baseline is established, however, the other three images grow up from the baseline.

If you want them to all grow down from the top, you need to change the vertical alignment of the images to `vertical-align:top` and they'll all grow down and right.

Additionally, you have the option of making them all grow up from the bottom by instead increasing the line-height of the parent container (`#main-links`, in this case) to match the height of the full-size images.

I tried `line-height:200px` and the first image grew up until it was half-size and then it continued down. I'm not exactly sure why that happened; my guess is something about `line-height` not translating directly to height. By increasing that `line-height` value to `400px` they all grew up from the bottom. (see [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/z0yc6rsw/2/).)

Comment: I mean i found a fix that worked for me, so it doesn't matter. It specifically says don't reply. So for you to give a thumbs down and then reply that you have issues makes no sense to me, I get your trying to help.

Comment: I didn't give a thumbs down; that was somebody else. I provided an answer both to benefit you so that you could learn why you had the issue, but also to benefit anybody in the future who finds this question and wants to know why their animation is acting weird.

Comment: You probably got the down-vote because you said "DO NOT REPLY" instead of simply posting your own answer. Most people who find the answer to their own questions post the answer so that others can see how they solved the problem.